# Browser Sync & XAMPP - not connection

Tags: google-chrome, gulp, xampp, browser-sync

I have problem with BrowserSync on my XAMPP apache.

It is my gulpfile.js (I removed unnecessary code - is only necessary to solve the problem):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('watch', function() {

    browserSync({
        startPath: '/test',
        proxy: 'localhost:80'
    });

});
```

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

When I run the correct path to the directory of my project I have no connections. In the code of page is not JS file from BrowserSync: 
[project page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRMGq.png)

When I given the wrong path on in code of page 404 is JS from BrowserSync:
[error 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUOKh.png)

I used latest version Gulp, BrowserSync & XAMPP.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a couple of things:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
```

and in your task:

```
browserSync.init ({
```

Try those and see if that helps.